# System Monitoring Redundancy

Tags: monitoring, redundancy, availability

I consult in a small business environment where I have two HyperV hosts (with <10 VMs) + a couple other servers.

I recently had an issue where one of the HyperV hosts had a CPU issue and it came down, bringing most of my non-critical VMs with it, plus a free piece of software that I use for network & system monitoring and availability.  Because of this, and the fact that iDRAC locked up also, I did not get any alerts about the crash.

So I am wondering how I can (cheaply) get a redundant availability monitoring system in place--Is is as simple as running Nagios or Zenoss (or whatever) on two different HyperV hosts?

It just seems like running more than one copy of Nagios/Zenoss/etc could be expensive and have high overhead.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I am wondering how I can (cheaply) get a redundant availability monitoring system in place--Is is as simple as running Nagios or Zenoss (or whatever) on two different HyperV hosts?

Yes.

Redundancy means having more than one of a critical component. Monitoring is a critical component, therefore you need more than one monitoring host.  To solve the immediate problem you mention in your question you just need to set up a second canary on a separate host.
(Note that it doesn't have to be a full-on duplicate of your monitoring environment if continuity in monitoring isn't critical to you: It could just be a nagios check or similar to ensure that the main host is up and running).

---

More complex solutions include monitoring failover, and you may want also to consider an external monitor (there are lots of services like [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) that offer this) to monitor your more critical customer-facing systems as well, but first-glance impressions are that both of these are overkill for what you want -- you just need to be told if your monitoring system has died.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do you monitor a monitoring server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/209390/how-do-you-monitor-a-monitoring-server)

In a nutshell, get an external monitoring system to monitor your local monitoring - **if you can expose this to the web**. That can be as simple as hosting a website on your internal monitoring servier, which is monitored by a good 3rd party service.

Answer (score 0):

[spicework](http://www.spiceworks.com/features/?net=search&kwid=83daa30dbf9049ddbdecee3bd1deb316) is a free monitoring tool which can help you monitor your non-critical VMs easily.

Comment: I was running spiceworks on the VM host that crashed.  Hence, no alerts when it went down.

Comment: well, every alert system may get crash. So it is better to set up two alert systems for high availability. I would like to suggest you set two spicework instances if redundant is super important for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setup something like Pingdom to monitor the monitoring host?

Comment: Because they are internal hosts.  Pingdom monitors externally accessible hosts.